# Understanding Arc Consistency 4 in the context of Wave Function Collapse

Tags: graphs, constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming

Following this blog post about the [Arc Consistency algorithms](https://www.boristhebrave.com/2021/08/30/arc-consistency-explained/). Namely, the explanation on AC4. Consider the following example:

[image]

If I understand AC problems correctly. Then:

- We have two known variables `{X,Y}`.
- `domain(X) = {1,2,3}` and `domain(Y) = {2,3,4,5}`
- The constraint table can be defined as `(X,Y)=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,2),(2,4),(3,3)]` and two rogue constraints under `Y` as `(Y,_)=[(3,?),(5,?)]`. I did not include the additional variable(s) for simplicity.

Consider "collapsing" the domain of `X` into `3`. If I understand the AC4 algorithm stated in the post, then this is the equivalent of removing `1` and `2` from `domain(X)`. Hence:

1. We add `(X, 1)` and `(X, 2)` onto "the queue" to be processed.
2. The queue pops both elements, decrement the support of values in the domain of `Y` one at a time.

Afterwards, we'll have removed domains `[(X,1),(X,2),(Y,2),(Y,4)]`. Hence, we're left with:

[image]

However, at this point, the algorithm stops working (or I'm not understanding something correctly). The instructions include adding "eliminated" domains onto the queue, decrementing the support of related domain values until it reaches `0`, at which point you'd considering such domain value also "eliminated", but common sense tells us that since we chose `X=3`, the only remaining choice for `Y` is `3`, but the algorithm skips this additional inference, of eliminating `5` from `Y`. Hence this "propagation" will only happen at most once.

Help me understand the correct algorithm. What is it that should happen instead?